# Searching For Existing Values in Array

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to search for an existing value in an array like below

```
var values = []
values.push(localStorage.getItem('items'));

console.log(values);

if (values.includes(2)) {
  alert('Already Exists.');
}
```

When i console the array `values` i have output as `["1,2,3,4,5,6"]` so the code treats the array as having just one index which is `index[0]` which makes the search quite challenging for me.

My challenge is how to find the value `2` in the array `values` ?

Comment: Note that jQuery is not applicable to this issue - it's a framework primarily used for amending the DOM. When working with arrays you just need plain Javascript. I've amended the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage` can only hold strings. As such you need to convert the value you retrieve in to an array, which can be done using `split()`.

Also note that the resulting array will contain string values, so you need to use `includes('2')`. Try this:

```js
var values = "1,2,3".split(','); // just for this demo
//var values = localStorage.getItem('items').split(',');
console.log(values);

if (values.includes("2")) {
  console.log('Already Exists.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```js
    var names_arr = '["1,2,3,4,5,6"]'; 
names_arr = names_arr.replace("'",'');
 
function checkValue(value,arr){
  var status = 'Not exist';
 
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var name = arr[i];
    if(name == value){
      status = 'Exist';
      break;
    }
  }

  return status;
}
console.log('status : ' + checkValue('3', names_arr) );
console.log('status : ' + checkValue('10', names_arr) );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this isn't jQuery, it's vanilla JS.

Second, after doing `localStorage.setItem("items", [1,2,3,4,5,6]);`, `items` in local storage will equal to `"1,2,3,4,5,6"`, which is no longer the appropriate format.

Rather, save your array with `localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5,6]));`. When you want to retrieve those items, write `let vals = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));`, and search in `vals` with

- `vals.includes(2)` for a true/false answer,
- `vals.find(val => val === 2)` for 2 or undefined,
- `val.indexOf(2)` to get the index of the
  first element equal to 2.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

firstly get the values from local storage store it in a variable, split it using the split 
function, then check if the number is inside the array, alert the message if it returns true

```
var values  =localStorage.getItem('items')
    var spliter = values.split(',')
    console.log(spliter);

    if (spliter.includes('2') == true) {
      alert('Already Exists.');
    }
```